# React Navigation: How to free multiple screens while going back

Tags: reactjs, memory, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

In my app I have a list view from which a user can create a new item. During the creation process multiple screens are navigated through (using `this.props.navigation.navigate()`) until the new item is created. When the final step is completed I would like the app to return to the list view and free the memory used for all of the screens used when creating the new item. See this image:

[image]

My naive idea was to simply use `this.props.navigation.navigate()` again, to get back to the list view. But would this not mean that all of the screens S1, S2, ... , Sk are still in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reset`.

You should be able to use: `this.props.navigation.reset(ListView)`

Check [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset) post.

Comment: That does the trick! Although you need to do it with a NavigationAction as described in your link.